# Manage Azure Redis Cache with Azure PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, redis

When I try to run below command to just start with Azure Redis cache I am getting below error message. Am I missing something? I am using Windows PowerShell, Version 3.0.

PS C:> New-AzureRedisCache

New-AzureRedisCache : The term 'New-AzureRedisCache' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.

Comment: No worries.. I got it.. :)

I got to switch to Azure Resource Manager module using below command..

PS C:\> Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager
that's it.. and it worked.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have all the prerequisites complete (no Azure PowerShell commands loaded).  Follow the instructions at [Manage Azure Redis Cache with Azure PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-howto-manage-redis-cache-powershell/).

Comment: Thanks for the help.. :)